# After selecting a picture from the image picker in SwiftUI, unable to click on 'Done' button

Tags: swiftui, uikit

After select a picture from the image picker, I am unable to click on the 'Done' button. Can anyone explain why?

```
struct AddTodoView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @Binding var showAddTodoView: Bool
    
    @State private var displayImagePicker = false //
    @State private var photoImage: Image?//
    @State private var photoUIImage: UIImage?//
    
    func getImage(){//
        if let image = photoUIImage{
            photoImage = Image(uiImage: image)
        }
    }
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var selectedCategory = 0
    var categoryTypes = ["family","personal","work"]

    
    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text("Add Todo").font(.largeTitle)
            TextField("To Do name",text: $name)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .border(Color.black).padding()
            
            Text("Select Category")
            Picker("",selection: $selectedCategory){
                ForEach(0 ..< categoryTypes.count){
                    Text(self.categoryTypes[$0])
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            //
            Button("Select Photo"){
                self.displayImagePicker = true
            }.padding()//
            photoImage?.resizable().scaledToFit()//
            
        }.padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $displayImagePicker, onDismiss: getImage){//
            ImagePickerViewController(image: self.$photoUIImage)//
        }//
        
        Button(action: {
            print("pressed")
        },
        label: {
            Text("Done")
        })
    }
}
```

Seems that the focus has gone again from the main view to the image picker view. i.e. the print("pressed") in the Button doesn't get called.

Below's my ImagePickerViewController.

```
struct ImagePickerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
        var parent: ImagePickerViewController
        init(_ parent: ImagePickerViewController){
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: To avoid guessing please provide standalone reproducible example.

Comment: added ImagePickerViewControoller to my original post. Hope it helps!

Comment: work perfectly in my system.

Comment: after I select a photo, and the picker dismisses, I can't click on 'Done'. But if I just create the todo without selecting photo, I can click on 'Done' with no problem. Problem only occurs when I select a photo

Comment: Works fine for me. "pressed" appears in the console log when I tap the button. that's the only action you have in your code.

Answer (score -1):

oh yes, its working fine. problem was due to another line of code.